# Configure IDE Proxy Settings

Tags: visual-studio, batch-file, tfs, proxy

When running

```
tf proxy /configure
```

from the commandline, tfs sets the proxy settings based on AD sites set up within the TFS server.

If this is done before Visual Studio is run for the first time, it appears that VS takes these values by default. However, if you rerun the command, Visual Studio does not update with the new values.

I'd like to give my developers a batch file that configures their proxy settings for the office they are currently in. So that they could easily set up the values when they are in different offices, or if they are working remotely.

I've written the below:

```
@echo off
set TFDIR=%vs120comnTools%..\IDE
set Path=%Path%;%TFDIR%

tf proxy /enabled:false

echo[
echo Configuring Proxy
tf proxy /configure /collection:[MyUrl]
PAUSE
```

If I run this, it does appear to load the correct settings, and the `tf proxy` command returns the appropriate values. However, when I open Visual Studio and go to Tools >> Options >> Source Control >> Team Foundation Server, the proxy settings remain at the last values I set manually.

Is there a way to make the batch file update the visual studio settings.

**Update**

Thanks to Vickys answer below, I've realised that the problem isn't *quite* what I thought it was.

When I am running tf.exe, it is correctly updating the TFS Proxy settings for the installation of Visual Studio that is hosting the exe (i.e. the one I'm using the path to). However, it *doesn't* update the proxy configurations of the *other* installed visual studio installations.

Since I don't want to have to run the command for all installed versions, I'm looking for a way to make it update them all from a single command.

Comment: And the users running the batch file have the appropriate permissions? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee791981(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @Squashman Yeah, they are all local admins in their machines. I'm trying it on my machine right now, and I've started it from a powershell CLI running as admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Vickys [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33867678/2505574), I have been able to determine the `tf.exe` will update the TFS settings for the IDE that it is hosted by. e.g. if you are running `/14.0/Common7/IDE/tf.exe`, it will update the settings for Visual Studio 2015. It won't, however, update 2013, 2012, etc.

I have written the below powershell script that will update the other instances. You will need to update the [MyUrl] Value with the appropriate url for your TFS collection

```
#TODO: Replace [MyUrl] With the collection Url

#Add New Versions to this list when new versions of VS are released
$VsVersionsToDisable = "10.0", "11.0", "12.0", "14.0"

[System.Collections.ArrayList]$VsVersions = $VsVersionsToDisable
[String]$VsProxyVersionToUse = ""

#Find the Highest installed VS Version, and use it for the TFS.exe Command.
foreach ($version in $VsVersions | Sort-Object -Descending)
{
    $keyPath = "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\$version`_Config"
    If (Test-Path $keyPath)
    {
        $aliasPath = Get-ItemProperty -Path $keyPath | Select-Object `
                               -ExpandProperty InstallDir
        $proxyPath = Join-Path $aliasPath "tf.exe"
        set-alias proxyTF $proxyPath

        #Remove the VS Version we're using from the array 
        #the command will auto-set this value, so we don't need to manually set it.
        $VsVersions.Remove($version)
        $VsProxyVersionToUse = $version

        break
    }
}

#Gets the last Check time from the Auto-Configuration, to update the other
#versions
function Get-ProxyLastCheckTime()
{
    return Get-ItemProperty `
    "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\$VsProxyVersionToUse\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Proxy" `
    | Select-Object -ExpandProperty LastCheckTime
}

#For each installed version, updates the proxy settings.
function Set-VSIDEConfig
(
    [String]
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    $proxyUrl
)
{
    $lastCheckTime = Get-ProxyLastCheckTime

    foreach ($version in $VsVersions)
    {
        Push-Location

        $regPath = "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\$version\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Proxy"

        if (Test-Path $regPath)
        {
            Write-Output "Updating Proxy IDE Settings for VS $version"
            Set-Location $regPath

            Set-ItemProperty . Enabled $true
            Set-ItemProperty . Url $proxyUrl
            Set-ItemProperty . AutoConfigured $true
            Set-ItemProperty . LastCheckTime $lastCheckTime
            Set-ItemProperty . LastConfigureTime $lastCheckTime
        }

        Pop-Location
    }
}

#Disables the Current proxy Settings.
function Disable-VSIDEConfig()
{
    foreach ($version in $VsVersionsToDisable)
    {
        Push-Location

        $regPath = "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\$version\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Proxy"

        if (Test-Path $regPath)
        {
            Write-Output "Disabling Proxy IDE Settings for VS $version"
            Set-Location $regPath

            Set-ItemProperty . Enabled $false
        }

        Pop-Location        
    }
    Write-Output ""
}

#Process the response from the Proxy command.
function Process-ProxyResult
(
    [String[]]
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    $result
)
{
    $resultUrl = $result | Select -Last 1

    if ($resultUrl -match "Successfully configured proxy (?<content>.*)\.") 
    {
        $url = $matches["content"].Trim()

        #Update the IDE Settings with the new proxy
        Set-VSIDEConfig $url
    }   
    Write-Output ""
}

#Run the TFS Proxy Setup.
function Set-TFSProxy()
{
    #First, Disable the proxy settings
    proxyTF proxy /enabled:$false
    Disable-VSIDEConfig

    Write-Output "Getting Proxy data from Team02"
    #TODO: Replace [MyUrl] With the collection Url
    $output = proxyTF proxy /configure /collection:[MyUrl] 2>&1
    Write-Output $output

    Write-Output ""
    Process-ProxyResult $output
}

    #Run it by default.
Set-TFSProxy
```

Answer (score 1):

After you run the batch file, you need to restart Visual Studio.

Comment: That doesn't work. I don't have VS running when I run the batch file.

Comment: Ha. No, it does work. My question isn't actually what I thought it was. I was running with one \IDE\tf.exe version, but looking at a different VS installation. Basically, I want it to update them all from one command. I think I have a solution, but I'll update the question to reflect the actual issue.